# Is it the rails way to use singular or plural controller names?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Should I use /article or /articles ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use either. If you are defining your routes using resource(s) then it's best to use plural controller names, because that is the default:

```
resources :articles
resource :articles
```

But it is possible to specify other controller names as well:

```
resources :articles, :controller => 'article'
resource :article, :controller => 'article'
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use either. However, It is better to use the plural. 
A controller is a class that, most often, accesses more than one instance of a model.

Eg: For a model by the name `Subject`, a controller accesses lot of instances of `Subject`, viz., `subjects`. Therefore, we name `SubjectsController` instead of `SubjectController`.

Answer (score 2):

Plural

For the name of the actual controller class, and file it lives in. e.g `class ArticlesController...` living in `/app/controllers/articles_controller.rb`